# Change the background color of downloaded image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting some images from the particular site and its giving the image with white background.Is their any way to change background color of image from white color to clear color in objective-c.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post one of the images? How about the format? JPG / PNG? Is there any transparency in the images?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it is a pretty CPU intensive operation. IF the background is white and only the background, you can use `Quartz` functions to create a brand new PNG image were you had changed white pixel's alpha channel from 1 to 0. Why is that a pretty intense task? you need to examine the image pixel by pixel, an if there is a also a white color in your image this will be changed too.
 I think that is better to change the source image using photoshop or GIMP and convert it to a transparent background PNG, then you will be able to apply the background you want.